# Why I have to remove so many packages when I try to install zlib1g-dev:i386

Tags: installation, zlib

When I try to install zlib1g-dev:i386, I got below message:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 manpages-dev:i386
Recommended packages:
  gcc:i386 c-compiler:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dkms gcc gcc-4.7 nvidia-310-updates
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev:i386 linux-libc-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,605 kB of archives.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I have to remove `dkms gcc gcc-4.7 nvidia-310-updates`
Why? If I remove them , will my Ubuntu has problem? My Nvidia driver version is `310.44` , can I remove `nvidia-310-updates` ?